# Will computed property be dependent on a data property if I use data property only for checking if it is defined?

Tags: vue.js

I have this vue component:

```
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            editor: new Editor({
               //some options
            }),
        }
    },
    computed: {
        doc(){ // <--------------------- take attention on this computed property
            return this.editor ? this.editor.view.state.doc : null;
        },
    },
    watch: {
        doc: {
            handler: function(val, OldVal){
                // call some this.editor methods
            },
            deep: true,
            immediate: true,
        },
    },
}
```

Will computed property `doc` be dependent on a data property `editor` if I use `this.editor` only for checking if it is defined and not use it for assigning it to the `doc`? I mean, If I will change `this.editor` will `doc` be changed? Also, I have watcher on `doc` so I need to know if I will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Why not put a few `console.log` statements and check.

Comment: @ravikumar, I have a freezing page after some code modification, so, I am trying to understand how vue dependency system works. I mean understand, not guess. That is why I ask.

Comment: 1. In your handler you must use `Vue.nextTick()` for editor modifications to overcome recursive changes and freezing. 2. Your modifications may recreate in editor some structures and may lead to infinite loop without extra checking

Comment: @Darius, 2) it looks like it really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `doc` property computation, you use:

1. the `editor` property (at the beginning of your ternary, `this.editor ? ...`)
2. if `editor` exists, the `editor.view.state.doc` property

So the computation of `doc` will be registered by Vue reactivity system as an effect related to the properties `editor` and (provided that `editor` exists) to `editor.view.state.doc`. In other words, the `doc` property will be reevaluated each time one of these two properties changes.

**=> to reply to the initial question, `doc` will indeed depend on `editor`.**

This can be toned though, because by 'property change', we mean:

- for properties of primitive types, being reassigned with a **different** value
- for objects, having a new reference

So, in our case, if `editor`, which is an object, is just mutated, and that this mutation does not concern it's property `editor.view.state.doc`, then **`doc` will not be reevaluated**. Here are few examples:

```js
    this.editor = { ... }  // doc will be reevaluated
    this.editor.name = ' ... '  // doc will NOT be reevaluated
    this.editor.view.state.doc = { ... }  // doc will be reevaluated
```

If you want to understand this under the hood, I would recommand these resources (for Vue 3):

- [the reactivity course on Vue Mastery (free)](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/vue-3-reactivity/vue3-reactivity/)
- [this great talk and demo (building a simple Vue-like reactivity system)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HezB8UEU5Rg&list=PLCxzy-hmQq9HOg0mS0laLkMiTov2zyZ5q&index=23)

---

About the inifinite loop, the `doc` watcher handler will be executed only:

- if `doc` is reassigned with a **different** value
- in the case where `doc`is an object, if `doc` is mutated (since you applied the `deep` option to the `doc` watcher)

The only possibility to trigger an infinite loop would be to, in the `doc` watcher handler, mutate or give a new value to `doc` (or `editor.view.state.doc`). For example (cf @Darius answer):

```js
    watch: {
        doc: {
            handler: function(val, OldVal){
                // we give a new ref each time this handler is executed
                // so this will trigger an infinite loop
                this.editor.view.state.doc = {}
            },
            // ...
        },
    }
```

**=> to reply to the second question, apart from these edge cases, your code won't trigger a loop**. For example:

```js
    watch: {
        doc: {
            handler: function(val, OldVal){
                // even if we mutate the editor object, this will NOT trigger a loop
                this.editor.docsList = [] 
            },
            // ...
        },
    }
```

Comment: `editor` was added to the `doc` dependencies because editor's getter was called inside computed `doc` method. So, actually this is the answer to my question and you was much more clear. Also, I have some watcher with `val = {} and oldVal = {}` - these are different objects so they isn't equal despite they are empty - this was the cause of my infinite loop. I can mark your answer as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Changing `editor` variable should work, but changing `Editor` content may not, as it depends on `Editor` class and how it respects reactivity.

For example:

```js
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            editor: {text: '' }
        }
    }
}

...

this.editor.text = 'Text' // works
this.editor.text = {param: ''} // works
this.editor.text.param = 'value' // works
this.editor.param = {} // does't work, as creation of new property is not observable
```

If `editor` observer works and you are changing editor property in observer, which 'reinitializes' internal structures, it may lead to infinite loop:

```js
var Editor = function() {
  this.document = {}
  this.change = () => { this.document = {} }
}

var data = new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    editor: new Editor(),
    check: 0
  }),
  watch: {
    editor: {
        handler() {
            this.check++
            console.log('Changed')
            if (this.check < 5)
               this.editor.change()
            else
               console.log('Infinite loop!')                
        },
        deep: true,
        immediate: true
    }
  }
})

data.editor.change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
```

In such case, extra checking is necessary before making the change.